# DataTable can't change search box height

Tags: css, pagination, datatables-1.10

I'm having issues with making my dataTable pagination search box bigger.

I tried

```
   .dataTables_filter input {
       height: 30px !important;
}
```

which did nothing. I also tried

```
   .dataTables_filter input {
          min-height: 30px !important;
}
```

but that increases the space above and below the actual search box. I need the actual search box, where the words will be typed in, to be much bigger.

I know there are other suggestions out there to make a brand new input box, but I've had other unrelated issues with that as well so would like to make this one work if at all possible.

On the other hand, the width works perfectly.

```
  .dataTables_filter input {
       min-width: 300px !important; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some padding:

```
 .dataTables_filter input {
   height: 30px !important;
   padding:10px;
   border-radius:8px;
```

}